# How to check javafx based program run first time or not?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I want to show configuration page if its run for the first time else its show other pages. How can I implement in my netbeans project?

Comment: You'll save those configurations to a file, I guess. Just don't create that file before executing the program the first time and check, if that file exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but this might be the easiest:

Save your configuration at the applications startup to a persistent storage. You could use a database (e.g. h2), a file (e.g. txt/ini/config, XML, YAML, ...) or even the users registry with the Java Persistence API.

After that, on every startup the application loads that configuration and displays the appropriate configuration menu when either all or some information cannot be found.

That way you can also ensure that there is always a valid configuration in case it gets lost for whatever reason.